# Is there a way to assign one static elastic IP to multiple instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there anyway that many ec2 instances can share the same IP? So that all outbound API requests from the ec2 instances, are coming from the same IP address? If the API provider were to whitelist the single static IP address, it would grant access to all of the instances.

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is for outbound only, then it can be achieved using a [NAT Gateway.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)

All the EC2 instances will sit behind the public NAT Gateway, the NAT Gateway is then assigned an [Elastic IP Address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).

All traffic from the EC2 instances will be [routed via the NAT Gateway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwZoQZi-eYk) to the Internet Gateway and the target environment will see all the traffic originating from the Elastic Ip Address assigned to the NAT Gateway.

However, if traffic must go the other way (inbound), then this architecture will not work.

UPDATE: The NAT Gateway must reside in a public subnet, that subnet will have a route 0.0.0.0/0 to the Internet Gateway. The EC2 instances will reside in a private subnet and have a route 0.0.0.0/0 to the NAT Gateway in the public subnet.

Furthermore for High Availability it is recommended that you have at least 4 subnets, 2 in 2 different Availability Zones (AZ). A NAT Gateway does not span subnets and so at least two NAT Gateways should be used one in public subnet A which resides in the first AZ and the other in public subnet B which resides in the second AZ.

The architecture would be as follows:

[image]

Where Routing Table A (Associated with both public subnets) has a route to the Internet Gateway i.e.

- 10.0.0.0/16 - local
- 0.0.0.0/0 - igw-xxxxxxxxx

Routing Table B is associated with private subnet 10.0.10.0/24 has a route to the NAT Gateway in the public subnet (10.0.0.0/24) i.e.

- 10.0.0.0/16 - local
- 0.0.0.0/0 - nat-123456

Routing Table C is associated with private subnet 10.0.11.0/24 has a route to the NAT Gateway in the public subnet (10.0.1.0/24) i.e.
10.0.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0 nat-654321

[In this architecture](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#public-nat-internet-access) each NAT Gateway will have it's own Elastic IP address which means 2 IP Addresses will be visible to the target, if high availability is not important then you could use 1 NAT Gateway in one public subnet. Note that, [a NAT gateway supports 5 Gbps of](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) bandwidth and automatically scales up to 45 Gbps. If you require more bandwidth, you can split your resources into multiple subnets and create a NAT gateway in each subnet.

For more detailed information on configuring a NAT within a VPC see the [following page in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response, that makes a lot of sense! For api responses from the target environment, is there a workaround?

Comment: Depends what you mean by response? If the EC2 instance is initiating the request, and it is synchronous then it will come back the same way, if it is asynchronous, then there are a few ways to handle this. The easiest would be an Application Load Balancer, and the target sends requests to the load balancer, but then you would have 2 different IP addresses one for outbound and one for inbound.

Comment: I guess the question is why? if it is for security and you want to restrict traffic then if the target is on AWS, consider VPC peering or private link, else maybe a site to site VPN?

Comment: @ConorIsAMelon What do you mean by "api responses from the target environment"?

Comment: Sorry my explanation mightn't be great. I basically just need the ec2 webserver to make some API (post and get requests) calls to an external server. I'm just wondering if the response to these requests will come back through the gateway. The reason this is being done, is because every time I add an ec2 instance, I need to inform the guys in charge of the API to whitelist the new ec2 IP

Comment: @ConorIsAMelon, I understand, if you use a NAT Gateway with routing setup for 0.0.0.0/0 to go to NAT, the EC2 instances will not even know there is a NAT Gateway, they will call out to the target machine and be responsible for the connection, the data will flow back via the NAT Gateway provided the EC2 instances are the ones initiating the request and calling out to the API.

Comment: Ok great, if the instances were in a public subnet, would it still work?

Comment: @ConorIsAMelon no because the def of a public subnet is that it has a route (0.0.0.0/0) to the Internet Gateway. For this to work, the EC2 instances must be in a private subnet with a route (0.0.0.0/0) to the NAT Gateway in a public subnet which has a route (0.0.0.0/0) to the internet over the internet gateway